# Error message "Application does not support this device" using Embarcadero C++ Builder XE7

Tags: android, c++builder, c++builder-xe7

I'm writing a simple application with a form, buttons, labels, etc.

Running it in the emulator gives:

> Application does not support this device

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [Workaround for Android 4.0/Kindle Fire Message: "Application does not support this device"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Running_Your_Android_Application_on_an_Android_Device#Workaround_for_Android_4.0.2FKindle_Fire_Message:_.22Application_does_not_support_this_device.22)?

> When you try to run an Android app on a device running Android 4.0.x (including some
>   Amazon Kindle Fire devices), you might see this message:
>
> ***Application does not support this device***
>
> To workaround this issue:
>
> 1. In the IDE, open the [Deployment Manager](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Deployment_Manager) (Project > Deployment), and locate the following
>      entry:
>
>    ```
>    Local Name: libnative-activity.so 
>    *emphasized text*Remote Path: library\lib\armeabi\
>    ```
> 2. Uncheck the entry to prevent deployment of this file.

Also consider that:

- C++Builder Android compiler doesn't support emulators for the 2.x version (Gingerbread) because emulators for Android versions 2.x target an ARMv6 CPU, which isn't supported (ARMv7 only) (*)
- Android emulators cannot be run on a Virtual Machine. Although an emulator might run on a VM, the emulator will not actually run an application.

Further references:

- [Creating an Android Emulator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_an_Android_Emulator)
- [Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)

(*) Android for the Intel platform is scheduled [after 2014](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43677)

Answer (score 0):

[Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development) (Rad Studio XE7)

I'm using `Nox` with `Rad Studio 10`

`Nox` is a fast `android emulator` that works fine with `Rad Studio`

According to [this post](http://en.bignox.com/blog/?p=344) and this [Question (How to Connect Rad Studio 10 Seattle with Nox App Player)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083057/how-to-connect-rad-studio-10-seattle-with-nox-app-player?s=7%7C1.7439) You can connect your IDE with Nox App Player.