# How to Connect Rad Studio 10 Seattle with Nox App Player

Tags: android, delphi, android-emulator, delphi-10-seattle

According to this official blog post ([How to connect Android Studio with Nox App Player for Android development and debug](http://en.bignox.com/blog/?p=344)) it is possible to connect Android Studio with `Nox App Player`.

Now I can connect Android Studio with `Nox App Player` but this method does not work for `Rad Studio`.

I contact Nox support team and ask them for a solution, they told me:

> You can connect to Rad Studio by integrating Android development plug-in. Then forward through the command port (nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001) will solve the problem.

In the Rad Studio I set the path to Android SDK, NDK and Java (`Tools -> Options -> SDK Manager`) but still I can't connect Rad Studio with Nox.

Among many of Android Emulators I tested, the only Emulator that works with Rad Studio is *AVD* and *Nox App Player*, other emulators says "**Application Does Not Support This Device**". [[Android Devices Supported for Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development)]

AVD is too slow and sometimes it freezes or hangs and should be restarted but Nox is very fast and powerful.

What should I do to connect Rad Studio with Nox?

Comment: Connect to it using Indy on port 62001

Comment: Thank you for the reply, could you please explain how to do that ?

Comment: Did you try to run the command? See also http://en.bignox.com/blog/?p=344

Comment: yes developer mode is enabled

Comment: I can also run apps directly from android studio by executing `nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per one of the comments, you need to follow the instructions, here:

http://en.bignox.com/blog/?p=344

You also need to change the Adb location in the SDK properties of the Android SDK options in Delphi. It'll be something like this:

C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Nox\bin\nox_adb.exe

where [username] is the logged in username on your system. Then refresh the Target node under the Android target in the project manager in Delphi, and NoxW should appear.

It seems debugging isn't possible with Delphi and nox_adb, but this makes deployment easier

Comment: The above solution worked well, thank you so much for your answer. as an another solution I recently found, it is possible to keep the original `adb.exe` in Rad Studio SDK options and connect it to `127.0.0.1:62001` therefore, both `adb.exe` and `nox_adb.exe` are connected to the same port.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the other solution you found? Thanks

Comment: `adb.exe help` : Port 5555 is used by default if no port number is specified. I just changed it.

Comment: Changed what, and where?

Comment: from Nox bin folder run this command: `nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001` and from Android SDK platform-tools: `adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001`

Comment: It did not work for me,The program runs on Nox but Delphi does not debug (execute without debugging)

Comment: Which is exactly why I said: "It seems debugging isn't possible with Delphi and nox_adb, but this makes deployment easier"

Answer (score 1):

- Execute without debugging
- Do not run Rad Studio emulator, No if asked
- Drag and drop your apk projet file from the bin folder to Nox player